# row means without taking NAs / Blanks

Tags: r, dataframe, mean, na

lets say i have a data frame

```
names <- c('joe','bob','john','carl')
col2 <- c(1,4,3,4)
col3 <- c(2,10,"",7)
col4 <- c(3,10,7,4)


df <- data.frame(names, col2, col3, col4)
```

how do i get the 5th column to display accurate means?

```
df$mean <- 0

df$mean <- rowMeans(df[, c(2:4)])
```

... but since the str(df) of col3 is a factor, it is not computing correctly
I want the df$mean column to show c(2,8,***5***, 5) as the 3rd row should only take the mean of 3 and 7 (which equals to 5). I don't want to set the "" equal to 0 because then the mean for the 3rd row would be 3.333 which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df$col3<-as.numeric(as.character(df$col3))
df$mean <- rowMeans(df[, c(2:4)],na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: also, what would be the best way to apply this over all the columns? i.e. let's say i have 100 columns that all need to be as.numeric(as.character(df$col"i"). would you recommend a for loop?

Comment: no, loops in R tend to be very slow. Instead, use sapply: `df2 <- sapply(df[101:200], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))` where 101 and 200 are the indices where your 100 columns begin and end. If you want to apply it to the entire data frame, use: `df <- sapply(df, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))`